# Sorted insert method for a linked list?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So I need to create a method that will insert items into a linked list in increasing order. I've been trying for hours and can't get it to work. This implementation will only add the first element and the loop is never entered. However when I try anything else I get either an infinite loop or a null pointer exception. Please help point me in the right direction.

```
 public class List<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> { 
          ........
           public void sortedOrderInsert(T newElt) {
                Node<T> n = new Node<T>(newElt);
                Node<T> current = head;
                Node<T> prev = head;
                boolean added = false;
                if (head == null) {
                    head = n;
                    count++;
                } else {
                    while (current.next != null && added == false) {
                        prev = current;
                        current = current.next;
                        if (current.data.compareTo(newElt) >= 0 ) {
                            added = true;
                            n = current;
                            prev = n;
                            count++;    
                        }
                        else if (current.next == null) {
                            current.next = n;
                            current = current.next;
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```

This is my Node class.

```
private static class Node<D extends Comparable<D>> {
        private D data;
        private Node<D> next;

        public Node(D data) {
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that homework or not? If not, then a `SortedSet` implementation... Also, what do you do with duplicates?

Comment: instead of current.next != null , try checking for current != null in your while loop